# Group similar datas from an array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Here my array:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [NDC_Id] => 56
        [NDC_Date] => 2017-04-14
        [NDC_Type] => Night
        [NDC_Item] => Night
        [NDC_Rate] => 95.00
        [NDC_Quantity] => 1
        [NDC_Taxes] => 0
        [NDC_TaxesName] => 0
        [NDC_Provenance] => Room
        [NDC_ProvenanceRoomId] => 0
        [NDC_Status] => NotCharged
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [NDC_Id] => 58
        [NDC_Date] => 2017-04-14
        [NDC_Type] => Item
        [NDC_Item] => Petit déjeuner
        [NDC_Rate] => 16.00
        [NDC_Quantity] => 2
        [NDC_Taxes] => 5.000,9.975
        [NDC_TaxesName] => TPS,TVQ
        [NDC_Provenance] => Room
        [NDC_ProvenanceRoomId] => 0
        [NDC_Status] => NotCharged
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [NDC_Id] => 59
        [NDC_Date] => 2017-04-14
        [NDC_Type] => Item
        [NDC_Item] => Lit pour bébé
        [NDC_Rate] => 10.00
        [NDC_Quantity] => 1
        [NDC_Taxes] => 5.000,9.975
        [NDC_TaxesName] => TPS,TVQ
        [NDC_Provenance] => Room
        [NDC_ProvenanceRoomId] => 0
        [NDC_Status] => NotCharged
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [NDC_Id] => 57
        [NDC_Date] => 2017-04-15
        [NDC_Type] => Night
        [NDC_Item] => Night
        [NDC_Rate] => 95.00
        [NDC_Quantity] => 1
        [NDC_Taxes] => 0
        [NDC_TaxesName] => 0
        [NDC_Provenance] => Room
        [NDC_ProvenanceRoomId] => 0
        [NDC_Status] => NotCharged
    )
    [4] => Array (
        [NDC_Id] => 60
        [NDC_Date] => 2017-04-15
        [NDC_Type] => Item
        [NDC_Item] => Petit déjeuner
        [NDC_Rate] => 16.00
        [NDC_Quantity] => 2
        [NDC_Taxes] => 5.000,9.975
        [NDC_TaxesName] => TPS,TVQ
        [NDC_Provenance] => Room
        [NDC_ProvenanceRoomId] => 0
        [NDC_Status] => NotCharged
    )
    [5] => Array (
        [NDC_Id] => 61
        [NDC_Date] => 2017-04-15
        [NDC_Type] => Item
        [NDC_Item] => Lit pour bébé
        [NDC_Rate] => 10.00
        [NDC_Quantity] => 1
        [NDC_Taxes] => 5.000,9.975
        [NDC_TaxesName] => TPS,TVQ
        [NDC_Provenance] => Room
        [NDC_ProvenanceRoomId] => 0
        [NDC_Status] => NotCharged
    )
)
```

I'm trying to group the element when some values are equals and the date the same.

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $k = $item['NDC_Type'];

    if (!isset($result[$k])) {
        $result[$k] = $item;
    } elseif (
        ($i = $result[$k]) && 
        $item['NDC_Rate'] === $i['NDC_Rate'] && 
        $item['NDC_Item'] === $i['NDC_Item'] && 
        $item['NDC_Quantity'] === $i['NDC_Quantity'] &&
        $item['NDC_Taxes'] === $i['NDC_Taxes'] && 
        $item['NDC_TaxesName'] === $i['NDC_TaxesName'] && 
        $item['NDC_Status']=== $i['NDC_Status'] && 
        $item['NDC_Provenance'] === $i['NDC_Provenance'] && 
        $item['NDC_ProvenanceRoomId'] === $i['NDC_ProvenanceRoomId']
    ) {

        $result[$k]['NDC_Id'] .= ','. $item['NDC_Id'];

        $current_dates = explode(',', $result[$k]['NDC_Date']);
        $last_date = end($current_dates);
        if(date('Y-m-d', strtotime("{$last_date} +1 day")) === $item['NDC_Date']) {
            $result[$k]['NDC_Date'] .= ','. $item['NDC_Date'];
        } else {
            $result[$k. microtime()] = $item;
        }
    } else {
        $result[$k. microtime()] = $item;
    }
}

$result = array_values($result);
```

Problem is the `Petit déjeuner` and the `Night` are grouped but not the `Lit pour bébé` item.

Just before this line `$result = array_values($result);` I have a strange key name for `Lit pour bébé`. I have `[Item0.69717400 1494009685]` and it's not the same key name for both `Lit pour bébé`. Perhaps it's the problem ?

---

To reply to Sahil Gulati, the expected result should be the following:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [NDCId] => 56,57
        [NDCDate] => 2017-04-14,2017-04-15
        [NDCType] => Night
        [NDCItem] => Night
        [NDCRate] => 95.00
        [NDCQuantity] => 1
        [NDCTaxes] => 0
        [NDCTaxesName] => 0
        [NDCProvenance] => Room
        [NDCProvenanceRoomId] => 0
        [NDCStatus] => NotCharged
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [NDCId] => 58,60
        [NDCDate] => 2017-04-14,2017-04-15
        [NDCType] => Item
        [NDCItem] => Petit déjeuner
        [NDCRate] => 16.00
        [NDCQuantity] => 2
        [NDCTaxes] => 9.975,5.000
        [NDCTaxesName] => TVQ,TPS
        [NDCProvenance] => Room
        [NDCProvenanceRoomId] => 0
        [NDCStatus] => NotCharged
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [NDCId] => 59
        [NDCDate] => 2017-04-14,2017-04-15
        [NDCType] => Item
        [NDCItem] => Lit pour bébé
        [NDCRate] => 10.00
        [NDCQuantity] => 1
        [NDCTaxes] => 9.975,5.000
        [NDCTaxesName] => TVQ,TPS
        [NDCProvenance] => Room
        [NDCProvenanceRoomId] => 0
        [NDCStatus] => NotCharged
    )
)
```

Comment: Can you share your expected output?

Comment: When I run the code the key change to `[Item0.69717400 1494009685]` at a moment...just before `$result = array_values($result);`.

Comment: @SahilGulati, expected result added.

Comment: I hope my post will help you out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i am using simple `foreach` to gather and group items

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/788103)

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string = '
{  
    "0"  : {  
        "NDC_Id"  :"56",
        "NDC_Date"  :"2017-04-14",
        "NDC_Type"  :"Night",
        "NDC_Item"  :"Night",
        "NDC_Rate"  :"95.00",
        "NDC_Quantity"  :"1",
        "NDC_Taxes"  :"0",
        "NDC_TaxesName"  :"0",
        "NDC_Provenance"  :"Room",
        "NDC_ProvenanceRoomId"  :"0",
        "NDC_Status"  :"NotCharged"},
    "1"  : {  
        "NDC_Id"  :"58",
        "NDC_Date"  :"2017-04-14",
        "NDC_Type"  :"Item",
        "NDC_Item"  :"Petit dÃ©jeuner",
        "NDC_Rate"  :"16.00",
        "NDC_Quantity"  :"2",
        "NDC_Taxes"  :"5.000,9.975",
        "NDC_TaxesName"  :"TPS,TVQ",
        "NDC_Provenance"  :"Room",
        "NDC_ProvenanceRoomId"  :"0",
        "NDC_Status"  :"NotCharged"},
    "2"  : {  
        "NDC_Id"  :"59",
        "NDC_Date"  :"2017-04-14",
        "NDC_Type"  :"Item",
        "NDC_Item"  :"Lit pour bÃ©bÃ©",
        "NDC_Rate"  :"10.00",
        "NDC_Quantity"  :"1",
        "NDC_Taxes"  :"5.000,9.975",
        "NDC_TaxesName"  :"TPS,TVQ",
        "NDC_Provenance"  :"Room",
        "NDC_ProvenanceRoomId"  :"0",
        "NDC_Status"  :"NotCharged"},
    "3"  : {  
        "NDC_Id"  :"57",
        "NDC_Date"  :"2017-04-15",
        "NDC_Type"  :"Night",
        "NDC_Item"  :"Night",
        "NDC_Rate"  :"95.00",
        "NDC_Quantity"  :"1",
        "NDC_Taxes"  :"0",
        "NDC_TaxesName"  :"0",
        "NDC_Provenance"  :"Room",
        "NDC_ProvenanceRoomId"  :"0",
        "NDC_Status"  :"NotCharged"},
    "4"  : {  
        "NDC_Id"  :"60",
        "NDC_Date"  :"2017-04-15",
        "NDC_Type"  :"Item",
        "NDC_Item"  :"Petit dÃ©jeuner",
        "NDC_Rate"  :"16.00",
        "NDC_Quantity"  :"2",
        "NDC_Taxes"  :"5.000,9.975",
        "NDC_TaxesName"  :"TPS,TVQ",
        "NDC_Provenance"  :"Room",
        "NDC_ProvenanceRoomId"  :"0",
        "NDC_Status"  :"NotCharged"},
    "5"  : {  
        "NDC_Id"  :"61",
        "NDC_Date"  :"2017-04-15",
        "NDC_Type"  :"Item",
        "NDC_Item"  :"Lit pour bÃ©bÃ©",
        "NDC_Rate"  :"10.00",
        "NDC_Quantity"  :"1",
        "NDC_Taxes"  :"5.000,9.975",
        "NDC_TaxesName"  :"TPS,TVQ",
        "NDC_Provenance"  :"Room",
        "NDC_ProvenanceRoomId"  :"0",
        "NDC_Status"  :"NotCharged"}}';
$result = array();
$array = json_decode($string, true);
foreach ($array as $item)
{
    if(!isset($result[$item["NDC_Type"].$item["NDC_Item"]]))
    {
        $result[$item["NDC_Type"].$item["NDC_Item"]]=$item;
    }
    else
    {
        $result[$item["NDC_Type"].$item["NDC_Item"]]["NDC_Date"].=",".$item["NDC_Date"];
        $result[$item["NDC_Type"].$item["NDC_Item"]]["NDC_Id"].=",".$item["NDC_Id"];
    }
}
print_r(array_values($result));
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [NDC_Id] => 56,57
            [NDC_Date] => 2017-04-14,2017-04-15
            [NDC_Type] => Night
            [NDC_Item] => Night
            [NDC_Rate] => 95.00
            [NDC_Quantity] => 1
            [NDC_Taxes] => 0
            [NDC_TaxesName] => 0
            [NDC_Provenance] => Room
            [NDC_ProvenanceRoomId] => 0
            [NDC_Status] => NotCharged
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [NDC_Id] => 58,60
            [NDC_Date] => 2017-04-14,2017-04-15
            [NDC_Type] => Item
            [NDC_Item] => Petit dÃƒÂ©jeuner
            [NDC_Rate] => 16.00
            [NDC_Quantity] => 2
            [NDC_Taxes] => 5.000,9.975
            [NDC_TaxesName] => TPS,TVQ
            [NDC_Provenance] => Room
            [NDC_ProvenanceRoomId] => 0
            [NDC_Status] => NotCharged
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [NDC_Id] => 59,61
            [NDC_Date] => 2017-04-14,2017-04-15
            [NDC_Type] => Item
            [NDC_Item] => Lit pour bÃƒÂ©bÃƒÂ©
            [NDC_Rate] => 10.00
            [NDC_Quantity] => 1
            [NDC_Taxes] => 5.000,9.975
            [NDC_TaxesName] => TPS,TVQ
            [NDC_Provenance] => Room
            [NDC_ProvenanceRoomId] => 0
            [NDC_Status] => NotCharged
        )

)
```

**Solution 2:** [**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/788106)

**Change your code from this:**

```
$k = $item['NDC_Type'];
```

**This:**

```
$k = $item['NDC_Type'].$item['NDC_Item'];
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. What was the problem with my initial code and why you needed to make a new one? The problem with your actual code is that it do not take care if it's items were book during a consecutive day.

Comment: @qatari Try my second solution the problem with your code was grouping.. Try this https://eval.in/788106

Comment: @qatari Error was because of `NDC_Type` which is `item` 4 times, so adding a microtime with make it a new group, So you should group resultant array on the basis of `NDC_Item` and `NDC_Type`.

Comment: @qatari I am looking into it, still i have a doubt of getting your code stucked. My `1st` solution will work fine. But you can pick any one you want. Checking your code again..

Comment: @qatari I am sorry to say your current login not even work with grouping `NDC_Item` and `NDC_Type` For this particular example it will work, but it will not work in case when values are shuffles because of your this logic `if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime("{$last_date} +1 day")) === $item['NDC_Date'])`, My advice is to just group with `NDC_Item` and `NDC_Type` and keep on appending `id` and and `date`.

Comment: Hello, so in your idea, can I keep the grouping by consecutive date? How can I apply your suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: @qatari... No, dont do the grouping  on the basis of date.. do the grouping on the basis of type and item which makes your group identical. likewise i did in my first solution

Comment: Yes, but the date group is the core of my report.

Comment: can you share another sample array for which i can help you out...?